# How I can add obstacles in the arm navigation package(electric)

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, ompl-planning, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !!!

My name is Iván.I'm working with the arm-navigation package. It work excellently.
But now I have to add obstacles, and do not know how to tell the arm_naviagation where the obstacles are.

Could somebody give me a pointer?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11667/how-i-can-add-obstacles-in-the-arm-navigation-package(electric)/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You won't be able to run this tutorial until we release later this week, but this should give you an idea: [Adding Virtual Objects](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Planning Scene/Adding Virtual Objects to the Planning Scene). If you are using MoveArm you can also add virtual objects to the planning_scene_diff field in the MoveArmGoal and get your robot to plan and execute paths based on those virtual objects.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2011-10-25**:
Thanks for you answer!!, and yes , I'm usign whole package "arm_navigation" with Gazebo and hope for the future use with a real robot